# confusion of proving f(A)∩f(B) a subset of f(A∩B)?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

f:A↦B and S⊆A,T⊆A, then f(S)∩f(T)⊆f(S∩T)

We know that it is not.By setting A:{1,-3} B:{1,3},f(x)=$x^2$.

But what if f is one-to-one function?

How can we prove that ∀y(y∈(f(S)∧f(T)))⇒∃x(x∈S∧x∈T))?

Comment: Please edit the question so that it makes sense. You should be showing that: if $f:A\mapsto B$ and $S\subseteq A, T\subseteq A$, then $f(S)\cap f(T)\subseteq f(S\cap T)$.

Comment: Because the $x$ you're looking for is just $y$ itself, which necessarily belongs to $S\cap T$.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks,it is so weird that after we saying f is one-to-one function,then the proposition "∀y(y∈(f(S)∧f(T)))⇒∃x(x∈S∧x∈T))" become true without any proving.

Comment: You have to explain why $y\in S\cap T$, though, but there's really no new element.

Comment: @Bernard thanks,i have a new thought to prove it by contradiction,i don't know it is true or not.prove by contradiction,
∀y(y∈(f(S)∧f(T)))⇒∃x(x ∉  S ∨ x ∉ T))

but this situation occur iff f is not one-to-one function.

Comment: In general I try toavoid proofs by contradiction, as they often are less natural than direct proofs. In addition, many of the  so-called ‘proofs by contradiction’  are only proofs by contrapositive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are talking about $f(A) $ and $f(B) $ we can assume the function is onto also. Then you see the inverse exists and inverse images are well behaved with $\cup$ and $\cap$. And by bijectivity onto the image $f^{-1} (f(A)) =A$. 
In general if you don't want to use the above argument you can say the function has left inverse and using that you can achieve the same result.

So $f^{-1} (f(A) \cap f(B)) = f^{-1}(f(A)) \cap f^{-1}(f(B)) =A\cap B $ applying $f$ both the sides you will get the result.

Comment: Thanks,but what if the function is injective but not subjective,how can we prove that?

Comment: Yes as you are talking about $f(A) $ and $f(B) $ you are working inside the range and a one-one function is bijective to it's range

Comment: Alternatively, by injectivity you also get that the function is left invertible so the equations I wrote holds true as for any left inverse $g$ (I wrote $g=f^{-1}$)                     $gf= 1_A$.